# Delete registered devices with IoT

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I want to find out how to delete an IoT Device that has been registered with IoT and IoT Device Provisioning Service.

The device has been provisioned with IoT DPS (code not shown here), then registered via the code below. The device is deleted from IoT DPS.

```
var provisioningClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.Create(Globals.IotDpsGlobalEndpoint, 
                    Globals.IotDpsIdScope, 
                    new SecurityProviderSymmetricKey(Globals.IotDeviceId, DpsSymmKey, DpsSymmKey), 
                    new ProvisioningTransportHandlerHttp());

var regResult = await provisioningClient.RegisterAsync();
```

like below:
[image]

Question:

i am looking for code sample on how to delete device shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the sdk [`RemoveDeviceAsync(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager.removedeviceasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_RegistryManager_RemoveDeviceAsync_System_String_), try the code below, it works on my side.

The connection string you can find in your IoT Hub in the portal -> `Shared access policies` -> click `iothubowner`.

```
 public static async Task DeleteDevice()
    {
        try
        {
            var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("HostName=xxxx.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxx");
            await registryManager.RemoveDeviceAsync("<device id>");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error in sample: {0}", ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I found a really nice article that gives some other examples such as adding/deleting/enabling/disabling the device from IOT Hubs using the Microsoft.Azure.Devices NuGet package, see https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/07/26/bulk-import-of-iothub-devices/